# Firefox extension - password strenght measure

Tags: firefox-addon

I am developing an extension to firefox that indicates to the user what is the strenght of his passwords.
For instance, the user inserts a password on a password field and the extension will measure password strenght immediately.

What shoul I overlay, ths browser.xul?

What events should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add an event listener for the window "load".  This will be called on each new page load.

Then inside the load handler, you would find any controls that are password controls.  And for each password control found, you would add an event listener for when any text is changed.

Inside your handler for the password change, you would update your password strength meter.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
One question: is that possible to draw something near password field with the classification? For instance, each time the user inputs a password, ahead the control appears something indicating the strenght of his password.

Comment: Yes for sure you can insert new nodes dynamically, and update them dynamically.

Comment: Do you have any reference that I can see?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not, but you can search online, there are a lot of tutorials on XUL and firefox extensions.